# NavigationLink shows up in ScrollView wrong

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-navigationlink

I have encountered this problem during the Swift programming. I have this long frame that I created, here it is.

[image]

The main idea that this frame will be used in a horizontal Scroll View in different view, like this. It will be opening different view on tap.

[image]

Here's the catch. If we want to transition to different view, we need NavigationLink. In order to work NavigationLink needs NavigationView. When we add our LongFrame in NavigationView, this happens

[image]

If we tap on it, it will display View, but in small frame

[image]

And If we, for example, add our LongFrameScrollView somewhere, It won't even show up sometimes

I will provide the code here. My guess that should be connected to **.frame**, but without this line of code I can't create this frame(.

```
// FRAME ITSELF
import SwiftUI

struct LongFrameView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                PlayerView()
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(red: 0.268, green: 0.376, blue: 0.587), Color(red: 0.139, green: 0.267, blue: 0.517)]),
                                             startPoint: .leading,
                                             endPoint: .trailing))
                        .frame(width: 310, height: 62)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image("mountains")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 70, height: 62)
                            .cornerRadius(8, corners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft])
                        
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Text("Sense of anxiety")
                                .font(.custom("Manrope-Bold", size: 14))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            Text("11 MIN")
                                .font(.custom("Manrope-Medium", size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 310, height: 62)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LongFrameView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LongFrameView()
    }
}

// MARK: - WITH THIS CODE WE CAN DEFINE WHERE CORNER RADIUS WILL BE CHANGED OR NOT. DO NOT MODIFY

extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
struct RoundedCorner: Shape {

    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

```
// SCROLL VIEW WITH FRAMES
import SwiftUI

struct LongFrameScrollView: View {
        
    let rows = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(60), spacing: 10, alignment: .leading), count: 2)
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 10) {
                
                // PLACEHOLDER UNTIL API IS READY
                
                LongFrameView()
                
                LongFrameView()

                LongFrameView()

                LongFrameView()

            }
        }
        .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 10)
        
    }
}

struct LongFrameScrollView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LongFrameScrollView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationView` should be added as the first/top view. So embed your `ScrollView` with `NavigationView` inside `LongFrameScrollView` and removed it from `LongFrameView`. Inside `LongFrameView` you just need `NavigationLink`.

```
 NavigationView {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 10) {
            
            // PLACEHOLDER UNTIL API IS READY                
            LongFrameView()                
            LongFrameView()
            LongFrameView()
            LongFrameView()
        }
    }
    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom], 10)
}
```

Comment: It's working in a preview, yay. But it's still won't appear in the MainView.

Comment: I have a HomeView, where I use this LongFrameScrollView, and if I add NavigationView in my ScrollView it won't appear at HomeView. How should I fix it?

Comment: If I build this app on iPhone, it won't display. If I build this app in Xcode and look at the preview It will appear in a some sort of frame

Comment: @DmitriyKaminskiy As I said `NavigationView` should be at the top, so if the home view is the main screen then you need to embed the content of home view inside `NavigationView`.